# Woocommerce filter shop orders by attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filtering, product, orders

I have this code which I use to filter Woocommerce product page, products by attributes, please can someone help me tweak this to filter Woocommerce shop orders by attribute such as 'brand' or 'weight'.

I have tried changing it myself but it doesn't return any results, any help would be very much appreciated.

Original code found here> [Add a filter dropdown for specific product attribute in woocommerce admin product list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54527975/add-a-filter-dropdown-for-specific-product-attribute-in-woocommerce-admin-produc)

```
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'product_attribute_sorting_dropdown');
function product_attribute_sorting_dropdown() {
    global $typenow;
    $taxonomy  = 'pa_brand';
    if ( $typenow == 'product' ) {
        $selected      = isset($_GET[$taxonomy]) ? $_GET[$taxonomy] : '';
        $info_taxonomy = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
        wp_dropdown_categories(array(
            'show_option_all' => __("Attribute {$info_taxonomy->label}"),
            'taxonomy'        => $taxonomy,
            'name'            => $taxonomy,
            'orderby'         => 'name',
            'selected'        => $selected,
            'show_count'      => true,
            'hide_empty'      => true,
        ));
    };
}

add_action('parse_query', 'product_attribute_sorting_query');
function product_attribute_sorting_query( $query ) {
    global $pagenow;
    $taxonomy  = 'pa_brand';
    $q_vars    = &$query->query_vars;
    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && isset($q_vars['post_type']) && $q_vars['post_type'] == 'product' && isset($q_vars[$taxonomy]) && is_numeric($q_vars[$taxonomy]) && $q_vars[$taxonomy] != 0 ) {
        $term = get_term_by('id', $q_vars[$taxonomy], $taxonomy);
        $q_vars[$taxonomy] = $term->slug;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138113/how-to-filter-woocommerce-products-by-custom-attribute

Comment: @kaize thank you but that seems to be aimed at sorting on product archive pages, I would like to add sorting by attribute to the "Admin orders page".

Comment: I still can not find a way to do this, any help would be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: @LPackman, did you find a solution? I'm looking for the same...and couldn't find a solution yet.

Comment: @JohnSmith, no sorry never managed to find a solution.